# Pancakeswap - Price Impact too high

Tags: erc-20, liquidity-provider

I deployed my own coin and tried to set the initial token value on Pancakeswap. After setting the initial value I tried to exchange my BnB's to MY_TOKEN and got a notification, that my price impact is too high. It was on 99% and I don't understand why. I can only buy like 0.009 without getting the risk of a too high price impact (it's still high on 45%).

1 BnB gives 98% price impact

[image: 1 BNB gives 98% price impact]

That's how my liquidity looks like:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There isnt enough BNB in the liquidity pool (the LP has 0.01 BNB in it, so obviously if someone tries to buy 1BNB worth of the token, the price impact is going to be huge). The tx can still pass though, but not through pancakeswap frontend

Comment: Would it make sense to put more BnB into it so that the price impact will hopefully decrease?